# Meteor.JS - Yogiben Favourites - How Can I Show Title?

Tags: node.js, meteor, collections, favorites

I'm building a small app within meteor, using the yogiben favourites package to allow users to favourite select items in a collection.

Currently the below code only shows the ID of the favourite/post, rather than the corresponding title.

How can I show the title?

```
  <template name="favoritesSidebar">
  <div class="template-favorites-sidebar">
    {{#if myFavorites.count}}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">{{_ "favorites"}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
            {{#each myFavorites collection="Posts"}}
                <li>
                    <a>{{_id}}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>{{_title}}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>{{Post._title}}</a>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
 </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: what does your data look like?

Comment: Hi Mikkel. The favourites panel shows: iSfjghRJMEgnNDtAu or similar for each item favourited.

Comment: Please edit the post to show what your retrieved JSON data looks like

Comment: Hi Mikkel, thanks for your response. Do I enter a command into console to do that?